# Move data from one database to another in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, data-migration

I'm in the process of migration from dedicated servers to Azure. In my existing SQL Server, I have a few jobs that move data from live database to archives.

From what I have read so far, in Azure you cannot use cross database scritps. The other options I have seen include [Azure SQL Data Sync](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync/), [Azure Factory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-azure-sql-connector/) and maybe SSIS. I have to note that there's some logic on what data is archived and I need the ability to specify this in the query.

Has anyone some experience and what would you recommend?

Thanx

Comment: How can you say that it's not possible when you post several options already? Or are you asking about on-prem to cloud migration? Have you checked [the migration guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-cloud-migrate/) ?

Comment: I mean it's not possible using cross database queries like in standard SQL Server...edited the question

Answer (score 2):

You can use the copy feature inside of data factory to do this now directly in Azure.

[Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-copy-wizard)